# MongoDB-Spark connector closing the connection soon after launch

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm using MongoDB version 3.4.10, Spark version 2.2.1 and MongoDB-Spark connector version 2.2.1.

I have a scala spark program that continually polls MongoDB for new data via the MongoDB-Spark connector. I noticed that, only in our live environment, after the first or second poll the program just hangs (doesn't crash just stops, no more log output).

Looking at the log output this is the last line is:

```
18/08/02 11:13:59 INFO MongoClientCache: Closing MongoClient: [localhost:27017]
18/08/02 11:13:59 INFO connection: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:84}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

I'm unsure what could cause this. Has anyone else encountered something similar?

EDIT: Adding code which polls db.

Every time I need to poll, I load mongoDB data like this:

```
//sc is SparkContext
val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri"->twdbURI)))
return rdd.filter(doc => doc.getLong("time") > timestamp)
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to open the connection and save  to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. I was running my Spark and MongoDB application in a VirtualBox VM with 1 core. Setting the VM to have 2 cores fixed the issue. It seems that the Spark-MongoDB was failing because of this and not reporting the error.